# "export 'default' (imported as 'VueGridLayout') was not found in 'vue-grid-layout'

Tags: vue.js

I have installed Vue grid layout in my Vue application.
I got this error message even though I have perfectly respected the documentation on their website https://jbaysolutions.github.io/vue-grid-layout/guide/#npm

Here is my error :

`"export 'default' (imported as 'VueGridLayout') was not found in 'vue-grid-layout'`

My code :

```
<script>
import VueGridLayout from "vue-grid-layout";


export default {

  components: {
    GridLayout: VueGridLayout.GridLayout,
    GridItem: VueGridLayout.GridItem,
  },
  data() {
    return {

    };
  },
  methods: {},
};
</script>
```

In my webpack I added this :

```
 resolve('node_modules/vue-grid-layout')
```

Comment: "In my webpack I added this" - why? It shouldn't be there. This totally depends on your setup but it's not mentioned. Basically it should be available as default or `*` import, the former is more correct

Comment: Without this addition I have this error: 

in ./node_modules/vue-grid-layout/dist/vue-grid-layout.common.js
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (10106:31)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|     subModification.prepareStates(modifiers);
|     state.subModification = subModification;
|     subModification.startAll({ ...arg
|     });
|   },

Comment: You normally shouldn't have this addition and this error. This is a regular package that is supposed to be seamlessly imported. Again, this depends on your setup which is unknown.

Comment: Do you think it is Webpack that generates this error? My application was created with Webpack in Vue2 with the CLI.

Comment: It's Webpack that is responsible for gluing modules together, so yes, it should be . Can you clarify, are you using specifically Vue CLI? Please, provide package versions and current Vue and Babel (in case there's one) configs in the question. I'm not sure what could cause "Module parse failed" in this case, probably package versions are too old. You can try to add this module to Vue's transpileDependencies, also try to import `vue-grid-layout/dist/vue-grid-layout.umd.js` directly. And any way, `resolve` shouldn't be there.

Comment: I understand better the usefulness of Webpack, I tested to install the package in a project without webpack and it worked, I think I will do without it. I use Vue 2.5.2, Babel 6.22.1, Webpack 3.6.0, I don't understand the issue with Vue CLI

Comment: Vue ecosystem relies on Webpack, you won't be able to use some third-party libs without it. Webpack 3 is old, so is Babel 6. I'd expect it to work without problems with Vue CLI, which is just ready to use Webpack+Babel setup. If the problem persists, try to reinit the project with up-to-date Vue CLI.

Comment: okay I see, I just redid the project without Webpack and this work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to import like this:

```
<script>
import {GridLayout, GridItem} from "vue-grid-layout";

export default {
  components: {
    GridLayout,
    GridItem,
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I found the solution, I actually did like that for the import but I also deleted webpack from my project